# Предфильтры и постфильтры в java EE

Tags: java, java-ee

Всем привет.

Речть идёт о веб сервисах RESTful архитектуры.

Хотел узнать и попросить ссылки на примеры о таких фильтрах(тоисть сама идея).

Из прочитанного мною в книге я попал на объяснение.

Предфильтр применяется глобально ко всем ресурсам.

Постфильтр применяется уже после обнаружения соответствующего метода ресурса.

Не хватает хорошего примера в коде! Если кто сможет помочь с этим, буду признателен!

Comment: Вы [об этом](https://dennis-xlc.gitbooks.io/restful-java-with-jax-rs-2-0-2rd-edition/content/en/part1/chapter12/server_side_filters.html)? Для примеров по JEE есть неплохой [репозиторий](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples) (в частности, [фильтры](https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-samples/tree/master/jaxrs/filter)).

Comment: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html